# Can we assign address of two nodes as a next of a one LinkedListNode in C#?

Tags: c#, data-structures, linked-list, cycle-detection

I am solving one program from linked list data structure in c#, where I need to check that given linked list is NULL terminated or ends with cycle.
I want to check it with different test cases, but not able to pass cyclic linked list as an input.

How to pass an cyclic linked list as an Input?

[Problem from hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/detect-whether-a-linked-list-contains-a-cycle) will give you an idea, what I am trying to achieve?

Here is my code to achieve linked list showed in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irw1S.jpg)

```
private static LinkedList<int> InitializeLinkedList ()
        {
        LinkedList<int> linkedList = new LinkedList<int>();

        LinkedListNode<int> item1 = new LinkedListNode<int>(1);
        LinkedListNode<int> item2 = new LinkedListNode<int>(2);
        LinkedListNode<int> item3 = new LinkedListNode<int>(3);
        LinkedListNode<int> item4 = new LinkedListNode<int>(4);
        LinkedListNode<int> item5 = new LinkedListNode<int>(5);
        LinkedListNode<int> item6 = new LinkedListNode<int>(6);
        linkedList.AddLast(item1);
        linkedList.AddLast(item2);
        linkedList.AddLast(item3);
        linkedList.AddLast(item4);
        linkedList.AddLast(item5);
        linkedList.AddAfter(item3, item6);

        return linkedList;            
        }
```

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. Hackerrank already have an online verification tool that will call the code you provide, what specifically are you asking?

Comment: If you're trying to write something similar and want to build test cases, you will have to show us some code. You say you're not able to pass cyclic linked list as an input? Why not? Does the compiler stop you? Are you having a hard time figuring out what to write? Inquiring minds want to know.

Comment: Your updated question code doesn't match the picture. `AddAfter` will insert the item in between item3 and item 4. it's impossible to create cyclic linked list with the built in `LinkedList<>`.

Comment: "not able to pass cyclic linked list as an input" - why not, is this a code problem?  If the code you did post is relevant to your question, I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to create a cycle, [LinkedList<>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7(v=vs.110).aspx) are built up with [LinkedListNode<>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ahf4c754(v=vs.110).aspx) These Node contain the item value as well as the List, Next and Previous which are used for navigating, these members only have internal setters so you can't manually assign these. These are however set when we call `AddFirst`, `AddLast`, `AddAfter` or `AddBefore` on the LinkedList.

In theory we could set the First and Last to be the same LinkedListNode

```
        var item1 = new LinkedListNode<string>("one");
        var item2 = new LinkedListNode<string>("two");
        var item3 = new LinkedListNode<string>("three");

        var list = new LinkedList<string>();

        list.AddFirst(item1);
        list.AddAfter(item1, item2);
        list.AddAfter(item2, item3);
        list.AddLast(item1);
```

but If we try the following we'll get a "Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: The LinkedList node already belongs to a LinkedList." Exception

Answer (score -1):

Try following :

```
       static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            LinkedList<Node> ll = new LinkedList<Node>();

            Node node1 = new Node();
            Node node2 = new Node();
            Node node3 = new Node();

            ll.AddLast(node1);
            ll.AddLast(node2);
            ll.AddLast(node3);
            ll.AddLast(node2);

        }
        public class Node
        {
        }
```

Comment: That's not creating a cycle, it's just repeating one element in the list and then terminating.

Comment: No.  You are adding the same object twice into the list just like you want.  The linked list will contain 3 objects (not 4).

Comment: The question asks how to create a cycle in the list, not how to add an item to the list twice.